# How can I explode a string into a hash?

Tags: string, perl, parameters, explode

I have a string

```
"myhashkey?key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3&key4=val4"
```

that I want to explode into

```
myhashkey => {
   key1 => val1,
   key2 => val2,
   key3 => val3
}
```

I also want to collapse this back to the same string.

So far what I've come up with is pretty messy, using index and trying to build the values by hand

```
        $arg = $_[0];

#if arg has = it may be key=val string
        if(index($arg,'=') > -1 ){

#if arg has & character it might be key=val&key1=val

            if(index($arg,'&') > -1 ){

                #$arg =~ m/[=&\?]/
                @r = split(/[=&\?]/,$arg);
                my $hashkey = shift(@r)
                my %values = @r;
                return $class->$orig( key => $k, $value => \%values );
                ... 

            }else{
                @r = split('=',$arg);
                return ( key => $r[0], $value => $r[1] );
            }

        }
```

I don't know how expensive the index(), split(), and join() functions are vs other methods of accomplishing this. I was thinking maybe I could use map + grep but I wasnt sure how to create the rergex for grep.

I also don't want to reinvent the wheel so hopefully someone has a better idea of how to do this.

**updated**
BTW This is happening in the Moose BUILDARGS sub, so I don't want to use a module like URI to parse the string everytime.

This is how I'm using the function in BUILDARGS

```
my $w = My::Param->new( 'hashkey?key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3');
my $x = My::Param->new( key => 'x', value => '7' );
my $y = My::Param->new( 'y=123' );
```

Produces this on print Dumper(*)

```
{ 'key1' => 'val1', 'key2' => 'val2', 'key3' => 'val3' }
bless( { 'key' => 'hashkey', 'meta_info' => [ #0 'hashkey?key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3' ], 'value' => { 'key1' => 'val1', 'key2' => 'val2', 'key3' => 'val3' } }, 'My::Param' )
bless( { 'key' => 'x', 'meta_info' => [ #0 'key', #1 'x', #2 'value', #3 '7' ], 'value' => '7' }, 'My::Param' )
bless( { 'key' => 'y', 'meta_info' => [ #0 'y=123' ], 'value' => '123' }, 'My:Param' )
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case, the already invented wheel is named [URI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI)

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -MURI -e'
    $uri = URI->new("myhashkey?key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3&key4=val4");
    $h{ $uri->path } = { $uri->query_form };
    print Dumper(\%h);
'
```

Comment: ah using URI. That works. But does that mean it has to create a URI object everytime the sub creates this hash? I shouldve been more clear this is happening in the BUILDARGS{} sub, is there another way to do this?

Comment: @nodebunny, I fail to see your point. By the way, have you considered storing a URI object in your object? Instant access to a "million" useful methods.

Comment: yep just tried that and it does work =], I don't need the full URI module, just param parsing. Could I just export the query_form function?

Comment: @nodebunny, why don't you want to make a URI object every time?  Concerns about performance or memory use?  To that I'd say, profile the solution and see if you can live with the impact...

Answer (score 3):

While this would work (1):

```
my $str = "myhashkey?key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3&key4=val4";

my ($path,$data) = split /\?/, $str, 2;
my %h = (
         $path => {
             map {
                 split /=/, $_, 2
             } split /\&/, $data
         }
        );

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%h;
```

I'm thinking your objection to using URI is a case of premature optimisation.  Unless you know the overhead is significant, don't sweat it.

(1) - limitations include dealing with things like &'s inside your desired text. Under normal circumstances, such as URI's, this is handled with % escape sequences. However, I don't have the code to deal with that above.  It wouldn't necessarily be difficult to add (another map in there), but this could easily make coding maintenance much more expensive than simply using URI directly and incurring any (possibly negligible) overhead it may include.

Comment: Thanks for this +1. I don't have any objections per se to using URI except that the delimiters may not be URL-param-style, but i just used them here as an example. It's really just an encoded string that I'm trying to explode. I like what you did with map there ^_^

Comment: my ($path,$data) = m/([^?]+)\?(.*)/; my %h = map {split '='} split('&', $data); <<-- i prefer a regex, so question marks can be in the data part